# Stopping Jmeter test when all users in user.csv are done

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am working on a test plan in Jmeter.
I am using a concurrency Thread Group for my test and I am using a user.csv file to pass my users through it. I have set the Recycle on EOF as "False" and Stop thread on EOF as "True" as I want all the users to work only once. I set some time on "Hold Target Rate Time".

My problem is sometimes all the users are done and leaves but test doesnt stop and keeps going on as the time I have set on "Hold Target Rate Time" is more then the actual time all users took and I keep getting the this message in log file "INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stop Thread seen for thread bzm - Concurrency Thread Group 1-8480, reason: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of file:user.csv detected for CSV DataSet:users configured with stopThread:true, recycle:false
".

I want to stop the test as soon as all users are done. How should I do it. 
I am using a Beanshell sampler with this code:

```
if(${__threadNum} == 0)
{
    ctx.getEngine().askThreadsToStop()
}
```

But its not helping. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added a JSR223 PreProcessor and added following code.

```
if(("${LOGIN}" == "END"))  //Login is defined in USER.csv
{
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //fetch starting time
        while((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<7200000)  //Defining sometime to 
wait let threads end gracefully.
        {
            // Waiting for the Defined time.
        }
        //println("---Stopping---"); // // Testing Purpose
        ctx.getEngine().askThreadsToStop();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure your [CSV Data Set](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to be like:

   [image: CSV Data Set Config]
2. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) to your Test Plan and put the following expression into "Condition" area:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('foo').equals('<EOF>'),)}
   ```
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as a child of the If Controller and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setStopTest(true)
   ```